# PHP foreach loop with a array_key conditional for filtering array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-key

This might be a painfully obvious question, but here it is anyway...

I have a loop to create an filtered results from a multidimensional array,

```
foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) { 
    if (array_keys($v, 'today')) { 
        $todayArray[$k] = $v;
    } 
}
```

However if there is no results from the array_keys search i need to create a node in the array to specify no data found etc.

Comment: Did you mean `array_key_exists`?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? Please show the content of your array and tell us what you need to access.

Comment: I do not see anything "multidimensional" in this...

Comment: Can't help you if we don't know your array content/structure !

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your Array in your comment:

```
foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) { 
    if ($v['calendar'] == date('d/m/Y') ) { 
        $todayArray[$k] = $v;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use function and loop it

in example:

```
function arrayLoop($myArray, &$todayArray) {
  foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) { 
      if (array_keys($v, 'today')) { 
          $todayArray[$k] = $v;
      } elseif (is_array($v)) {
           arrayLoop($v, $todayArray);
      }
  }
}
```

but... like others I have not idea what you asking for :)
so more explanation please :D

Answer (score 0):

You mean when you're outputting the array you want to show "No results" when it's empty? Like this:

```
<?php

foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value))
        echo 'No results.';
    else
        var_dump($value); // sub value
}

?>
```

Comment: My array is a list of tide data:

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1382939520
                [height] =>  4.49
                [type] => High Tide
                [tense] => past
                [calendar] => 28/10/2013
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1382963280
                [height] =>  1.42
                [type] => Low Tide
                [tense] => past
                [calendar] => 28/10/2013
            )
  
    [2] ...